# protecting plist in ipad app

Tags: ios, plist

In my app I am saving service urls and their user/passwords in a plist in the documents directory currently. I want to move the user and passwords over to keychain and protect the plist files aswell.
I tried using the keychainwrapper class given in this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html), but couldn't figure out how to add items to it.

how do i add an array of dictionaries containing user name and passwords into keychain, and protect my plist files aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use keychain, best solution is using third party library([STKeychain](https://github.com/ldandersen/STUtils/blob/master/Security/STKeychain.h)). It is very simple to use it.

If you want to store array to keychain, what you can do is you can convert array to serialised string and store that string to one keychain. Or you can store dictionaries to several keychain if you like.

I don't understand why you still want to protect your plist? Keychain is enough, don't need to store it to plist anymore!

Comment: keychain is enough, but i still need to protect the data im writing to my plist for company security reasons

Comment: OK, if you do want to secure your plist, you can do some encrypt your value when you are about to saving that value. I believe you know something basic cryptograph, so just use it. If you don't know, try Stanford University online course related cryptograph. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: ok, that can work. While i was searching, I found some lines of code on forums that looked like "writeToFile:withProtection:..."